# How to return to previous dynamic path emberjs

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

given a modal to log in the user I want to return to the path from where the user pressed the log in button. As some other questions suggest I tried to save the previous path in the application controller to a global created in `App` under the name `prevPath`:

```
            pathMemory = null,
            previousPath: function(){
                if (this.pathMemory){
                    App.set('prevPath',this.pathMemory);
                }
                this.pathMemory = this.get('currentPath');
            }.observes('currentPath')
```

The problem is that I have dynamic paths so the router does not know what to load when I give him the `prevPath`.

The current solution is to use `window.history.back`, which is ugly and I suppose not the best way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [client side authentication of embercasts](http://www.embercasts.com/episodes/client-side-authentication-part-2), have a nice way to handle it:

Basically, you have a `App.AuthenticatedRoute`, where all routes that need authentication will extend. In the `beforeModel` hook, is checked if the user is authenticated, in that case the presence of the token. If the token isn't present the current transition is stored.

```
App.AuthenticatedRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  ...
  beforeModel: function(transition) {
    if (!this.controllerFor('login').get('token')) {
      this.redirectToLogin(transition);
    }
  },

  redirectToLogin: function(transition) {
    alert('You must log in!');

    var loginController = this.controllerFor('login');
    loginController.set('attemptedTransition', transition);
    this.transitionTo('login');
  }
  ...
});
```

When the login is performed and valid, the previous transition is take by `self.get('attemptedTransition')`, and is called `retry`. This will retry the transition, in the case, the transition where the user attempted go to, before the login authentication redirect:

```
...
var attemptedTransition = self.get('attemptedTransition');
  if (attemptedTransition) {
    attemptedTransition.retry();
    self.set('attemptedTransition', null);
  } else {
    // Redirect to 'articles' by default.
    self.transitionToRoute('articles');
  }
  ...
```

With this, you will have the same behavior.

I hope it helps.