# Transition back to origin route

Tags: javascript, ember.js

So. I have a very simple problem, that should have a simple solution. I'm just not seeing it.

In my ember app, I have a login route, and a link to this in the header. You click this, and get to a login form. When successfully logged in, I want to go back to the route displayed before the login form.

Something like the following url sequence

/post/209 - user clicks login
/login - user provides credentials, submits, and
/post/209 - is displayed

Comment: I answered something similar to this some time ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18659651/how-to-return-to-previous-dynamic-path-emberjs/.

Comment: I'm already using that technique when transitioning to a route that requires logging in (e.g. /post/new). Hower, in my case, the first route (/post/209) doesn't require the user to log in, so the transition to that page is already completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, you can use the didTransition hook on Router, like this

```
App.Router.reopen({
    didTransition: function(infos) {
        this._super(infos);
        var currentRoute = infos[infos.length - 1];

        this.send('routeChanged', {
            route: currentRoute.name,
            context: currentRoute.context
        });
    }
});
```

infos contains an array of the active routes after transitioning. E.g. transition to PostEdit, the active routes will be

- infos[0].name = 'application'
- infos[1].name = 'post'
- infos[2].name = 'post.edit'

In my application i catch the routeChanged event in ApplicationRoute, and keep a stack of the last ones in ApplicationController. The second entry in this stack is used to transition to the previous route.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this out and this may not be the most elegant solution, but could you not simply do `window.history.back()` and the Router will take care of the rest?

Comment: I thought about that, but that would screw things up if the user is going straight to the login route from another page or a new tab.

Comment: Well in that case the behavior is undefined, but I guess you could just redirect to the index route?

Answer (score -1):

Login page link should be a GET request with a link to the previous page.

like the following Ex, twitter

https://twitter.com/login?redirect_after_login=%2FitsWillyFerrell%2Ffollowers

Observe the `redirect_after_login` field is pointing to the username of the persons page I came from, so you have a place to go to once after login.

Comment: Downvoter - please comment on the reason behind the downvote?

Comment: I wasn't the one downvoting, but I guess the reason is that your answer wasn't too relevant in the ember.js context. Thanks anyway

Comment: Yes, your answer was not really related to Ember.js.

Comment: :( Thought this might serve as a generic answer.